# How to monitor clicks on an ad link on my website

Tags: php

I have just written an ad rotator using mysql and php. Ads are randomly displayed on my website. There is a `click` column in the ad table. The url of the ad is the direct link to user's website ie: www.myshop.com.

The question is: How can i record if there is anyone clicks on that ad link so that i can save and store it in `click` column of that ad?

I tried to search on google but it kept telling me about google analytics blah blah... Please if someone has experience about this, please tell me what technique should I use to archieve this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

addd an onClick event on this ad element,then you can save the click event and redirect to the dest url in the  callback  function

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and I solved it using jQuery and Ajax. Here is how i solved it. Add a class say '`ad_link' to the`` tag. By using jQuery bind this to an ajax call.

```
$("a.ad_link").on("click",function(){
    var d = {url:$(this).attr('href')};
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : "save.php",
        data : d,
        success : function(e){
            //if you have anything to output to user then show it here
        }
    });
});
```

save.php

```
<?php

$link = $_GET['url'];
$user = $_SESSION['user'];//assuming that you have ur user id in session

//now you have the data, use the db connection to store these values accordingly
```

I hope this helps.